# Find expression for $c^2\in \mathbb{C}$ given certain parameters

Tags: complex-numbers

> Let $a,b,\theta,\phi \in \mathbb{R}^+$. Let $z,w,c \in \mathbb{C} / z=ae^{i(\theta+\phi)},w=be^{i\phi},c=|z-w|$.
>
> Then:
>
> (A) $c^2=a^2+b^2$
>
> (B) $c^2=a^2+b^2 -2absin(\theta)$
>
> (C) $c^2=a^2+b^2 -2abcos(\theta)$
>
> (D) $c^2=a^2+b^2 +2abcos(\theta)$

Comment: Do you mean $c^2={}$ instead of $c={}$? Also, what have you tried? Where are you stuck? Are $a,b,\phi$ and $\theta$ real numbers?

Comment: Yeah exactly that, thanks. About telling the right option right away, how?

Comment: Oh, I just used the feature of this page to answer myself an save the resolution. Below is my own answer.

Comment: Two of the answers have $-$ in them, one has $+$ and one has nothing. Thus the correct answer has $-$. Two of the answers have $\cos$, one has $\sin$ and one has nothing. Thus the correct answer has $\cos$. This isn't a foolproof method, but it happens when the problem is authored by someone who didn't think through the options, and instead took the correct answer and let each incorrect answer result from one change. This would've been much better if $a^2+b^2+ab\sin\theta$ had been a fifth option (you want to keep option A because that's a plausible wrong answer by itself).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $z\in \mathbb{C}$ and we have $|z|$ and $\phi$. Then if $z=a+bi$ we know that $a=|z|cos(\phi)$ and $b=|z|sin(\phi)$.

> So $z=a.e^{i(\theta+\phi)}=a.cos(\theta+\phi)+a.sin(\theta+\phi)i$.

> Similarly, $w=b.e^{i\phi}=b.cos(\phi)+b.sin(\phi)i$.

So now

> $z-w=a.cos(\theta+\phi)+a.sin(\theta+\phi)i-b.cos(\phi)-b.sin(\phi)i$

Then

> $c=|z-w|=\sqrt{[a.cos(\theta+\phi)-b.cos(\phi)]^2+[a.sin(\theta+\phi)-b.sin(\phi)]^2}$

Some math later

> $c=\sqrt{a^2cos^2(\phi+\theta)+b^2cos^2(\phi)-2ab.cos(\theta+\phi)cos(\phi)+a^2sin^2(\phi+\theta)+b^2sin^2(\phi)-2ab.sin(\theta+\phi)sin(\phi)}$

Now we use trigonometric properties (sum of squares and product)

> $c=\sqrt{b^2+a^2-2ab[\frac{1}{2}(cos(\theta+2\phi)+cos(\theta))]-2ab[\frac{1}{2}(cos(\theta)-cos(\theta+2\phi))]}$

Some math later again

> $c=\sqrt{a^2+b^2-2ab.cos(\theta)}$

Finally

> $c^2 = a^2+b^2-2ab.cos(\theta)$